# Prevent a Ruby script from running

Tags: ruby

Whenever I load a ruby class file in a different ruby file, it executes the class file being imported. This class file currently instantiates and calls the methods, outside the class definition. Is there a way to prevent the imported file from executing? This happens when I run unit tests too. I tried the following:

```
load 'file.rb'
require_relative 'file'
require "./file.rb"
```

Thank you.

Here's what I have in the class file (that I'm trying to import):

```
class Nim
   #some stuff
end

nim = Nim.new(Player.new)
nim.start_game
nim.configBoard
```

Comment: What would be the point of importing the file if you don't want to run it?  If it doesn't run, it will do *nothing*.  There will be no classes or variables or methods defined by the file because it never ran.  You should change the file so it doesn't have method calls outside of the specific class definition that you need from it.

Comment: Can you show me an example. My class file needs to print the necessary information when it's run. Is there a way to import just the class without executing the function calls? I was told that there was but can't get it to work.

Comment: What do you have in there at the moment? That's quite crucial to working out what's going wrong for you (edit it into your question)

Comment: Do you control this file you're trying to import? If so you shouldn't be doing anything besides declaring your class.

Comment: Typically, you'd declare your Nim class in one file, and keep the 'client' code (the code that instantiates and runs your class) in a separate file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change your file too look like the following:

```
class Nim
  # some stuff
end

if __FILE__ == $0
  nim = Nim.new(Player.new)
  nim.start_game
  nim.configBoard
end
```

This will only execute those method calls if the file is ran as a script rather than loaded as a library.

Comment: EXACTLY WHAT I WAS LOOKING FOR!!! THANK YOU! I saw this somewhere but wasn't sure how to use it. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I can't upvote you because I don't have enough reputation. Thanks again!

Comment: I still disagree that this is the right way to go about this...  A class file should *only* be declaring that class, and maybe requiring dependencies.  Nothing else.

Comment: @nzifnab I agree. Will update answer shortly to reflect as such for future readers.